# how to return a web page from a maven project

Tags: java, maven, jsp

I am trying to return web pages using a maven project. This works for html pages, but I need JSP. When I try to load a JSP page on http://localhost:8080/home the console says that the initialization of the dispatcherservlet has started an completed, but the webpage is not returned to the browser.

here's the code:

the main class:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.example")
@EnableWebMvc
public class DemoApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("static/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver
   }



    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

and my controller class:

```
package com.example.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

     @RequestMapping(value="/home")
        public String home(){
            return "home";
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be good if you provide what response you got.
you can try to add `@ResponseBody`to controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
     @RequestMapping(value="/home")
     @ResponseBody
        public String home(){
            return "home";
        }
}
```